# How to create a line-spacing command like `\doublespacing` but for an arbitrary factor?

Tags: macros, line-spacing, setspace, xfp

The `setspace` package provides a couple of multi-line spacing commands, like `\doublespacing`. But as far as I can see, it does not provide a simple spacing command by an arbitrary factor. It provides `\setstretch` but that just multiplies the `\baselineskip` rather than the font-size as `\doublespacing` does, so `\doublespacing` and `\setstretch{2}` lead to different spacing. I am wondering why there is no such command and whether one could create one. My attempt (based on the definition of `\doublespacing` in `setspace`) so far is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xfp}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\multispacing}[1]{%
  \setstretch {\fpeval{round(#1*10/12, 3)}}%  default
  \ifcase \@ptsize \relax % 10pt
    \setstretch {\fpeval{round(#1*10/12, 3)}}%
  \or % 11pt
    \setstretch {\fpeval{round(#1*11/13.6, 3)}}%
  \or % 12pt
    \setstretch {\fpeval{round(#1*12/14.5, 3)}}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\multispacing{3}

\begin{document}
First line

Second line
\end{document}
```

**Edit**

I have found out why it did not compile and changed the code accordingly. Now I am only wondering why no such command is provided by the `setspace` package.

Comment: Because TeX had no floating point arithmetic when setspace was written

Comment: The purpose of setspace is to emulate the double spacing switch on a typewriter, as required by many backward and bureaucratic organizations.  It works best with \raggedbottom and ttfamily fonts.

Comment: That's interesting. I have seen many people giving advice to use `\doublespacing` to get a double spaced document as required by many modern journals. But it is not the same as double spacing in other word processors. So you might be right about the purpose of that command. However, the package itself also provides the setstretch option which works differently and as in modern word-processed, it seems to me.